# How can we highlight multiple buttons at a time in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm developing a winform application in C# in which numbers from 0 to 99 in displayed on buttons name. If we clicked on a particular button say 16, all the Back Color of buttons starting from that button "16" is changed like green for Even number and red for Odd number. 
Now I'm trying to highlight all even numbered button at a time, but couldn't. Please help me how can i highlight all  even numbered button at a time. Here is my code and Thanks in advance.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // flowLayoutPanel1 is the name of the FlowLayoutPanel I used
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
               Button newButton = new Button();
               newButton.Height = 30;
               newButton.Width = 30;

               newButton.Name = "DynBtn" + i;
               newButton.Text = i.ToString();

               newButton.Click += newButton_Click;
               flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
           }
       }
       void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Button newButton = sender as Button;

           String buttonName = newButton.Name;

           int suffix = Convert.ToInt16(buttonName.Substring(6, 1));
           int start = suffix;

           for (int i = start; i < 100; i++)
           {
              Button nextButton = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls["DynBtn"+suffix] as Button;

              if (i % 2 == 0)
              {
                  nextButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
              }
              else
              {
                 nextButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
              }
              suffix++;
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: i used nextButton.focus(); in for loop of  newButton_Click() but it is not effective.

Comment: why in the line int suffix = Convert.ToInt16(buttonName.Substring(6, 1)); you set lenght 1? What you expect if suffix > 9?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       Button newButton = sender as Button;
       int buttonText = Convert.ToInt32( newButton.Text);
          foreach(Control c flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
          {
              if (c is Button)
              {
                 Button newBtn = (Button)c;
                 int _val = Convert.ToInt32(newBtn.Text);
                  if(_val > buttonText)
                  {
                   if(_val % 2 == 0)
                     newBtn.BackColor = Color.Green;
                   else
                     newBtn.BackColor=Color.Red;
                  }
             }
          }
   }
```

Comment: Read question carefully. ** If we clicked on a particular button say 16, all the Back Color of buttons starting from that button "16" is changed like green for Even number and red for Odd number.**

Comment: @Wulworine thanks, does it will work according to requirements..?? Have i picked the question right...??

Answer (score 0):

Try following method.

```
    void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int start = Convert.ToInt16(((Button)sender).Name.Substring(6));

        Color c1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Button nextButton = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls["DynBtn" + i] as Button;

            if (i < start)
                c1 = SystemColors.Control;
            else if (i % 2 == 0)
                c1 = Color.Green;
            else
                c1 = Color.Red;

            nextButton.BackColor = c1;
        }
    }
```